# What is the correct way to create a 2 column UPW ListView?

Tags: xaml, uwp

In the olden days it was possible to create a multi-column List View which seems to have gone away in modern times (at least with UWP apps). What is the correct way to create a 2 column List View with columns header?

Comment: Has your question been solved? If not, please feel free to contact us.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could use DataGrid instead of ListView to do this. It is easier to generate a DataGrid with two columns. You could refer to this document to know [how to add DataGrid control to a page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics).

Xaml code:

```
 <controls:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Fruits,Mode=OneWay}">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}"/>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Fruits = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>
        {
          new Fruit(){Name="Apple",Price=12},
          new Fruit(){Name="Peach",Price=15},
          new Fruit(){Name="Kiwi",Price=18}
        };

    }
    public class Fruit
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```